# Using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Geometry in WCF service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, wcf

I am having this issue with using Geometry that is returned from a WCF service. As part of the service, I have added a service reference for the map service that I am using in this project. I am trying to return 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Geometry as a return type but when I assign the Geomtry to my result, it comes back with this error:

> 'Geometry' is an ambiguous reference between
> 'GIS.Services.Data.BoundaryMapService.Geometry' and
> 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Geometry'.

What needs to be done to resolve this issue?

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Geometry resultGeometry = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Values.Count(); i++)
                    if (attributes.Values[i] is PolygonN)
                    {
                        PolygonN featureExtent = attributes.Values[i] as PolygonN;
                        resultGeometry = featureExtent; // Error here...

                    }
```